# Slow MySQL query when adding an OR statement

Tags: mysql, performance, join, indexing

This is the query I am trying to optimize:

```
SELECT SUM(`backend_ubqstat`.`complementary_revenue`) AS `complementary_revenue__sum`, SUM(`backend_ubqstat`.`revenue`) AS `revenue__sum` FROM `backend_ubqstat` 
INNER JOIN `backend_ubq` ON ( `backend_ubqstat`.`ubq_id` = `backend_ubq`.`id` ) 
WHERE 
(`backend_ubqstat`.`store_number` = 389 AND (`backend_ubqstat`.`week_of_year` = 2 OR `backend_ubqstat`.`week_of_year` = 3) 
AND (`backend_ubq`.`department` = 'QUINCAILLERIE' OR `backend_ubq`.`department` = 'OUTILLAGE') 
AND (`backend_ubq`.`sub_department` = 'Outillage à moteur' OR `backend_ubq`.`sub_department` = 'Outillage à main' OR `backend_ubq`.`sub_department` = 'Outil d\'assemblage'));
```

This query takes 73 seconds to execute. The same query on only one week (`backend_ubqstat`.`week_of_year` = 2 without the OR):

```
SELECT SUM(`backend_ubqstat`.`complementary_revenue`) AS `complementary_revenue__sum`, SUM(`backend_ubqstat`.`revenue`) AS `revenue__sum` FROM `backend_ubqstat` 
INNER JOIN `backend_ubq` ON ( `backend_ubqstat`.`ubq_id` = `backend_ubq`.`id` ) 
WHERE 
(`backend_ubqstat`.`store_number` = 389 AND (`backend_ubqstat`.`week_of_year` = 2) 
AND (`backend_ubq`.`department` = 'QUINCAILLERIE' OR `backend_ubq`.`department` = 'OUTILLAGE') 
AND (`backend_ubq`.`sub_department` = 'Outillage à moteur' OR `backend_ubq`.`sub_department` = 'Outillage à main' OR `backend_ubq`.`sub_department` = 'Outil d\'assemblage'));
```

takes 0.1 second to execute. I am trying to understand what is the major issue with the first query.

This query calculates the sum of the revenues of some products over a period of week on specific stores.

I ran EXPLAIN on both query with theses results:

Multiple weeks (first query):

```
+----+-------------+-----------------+--------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------+---------+------------------------------------+------+------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table           | type   | possible_keys                                                                                                                                                                            | key                                               | key_len | ref                                | rows | Extra                              |
+----+-------------+-----------------+--------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------+---------+------------------------------------+------+------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | backend_ubqstat | range  | backend_ubq_store_number_4ba08aefde7a0fdc_uniq,backend_ubq_ubq_id_2883f2962b976ce1_uniq,backend_ubq_week_of_year_534972be244e06dd_uniq,backend_ubqstat_week_of_year_1f3b84a6cf9999f7_idx | backend_ubqstat_week_of_year_1f3b84a6cf9999f7_idx | 4       | NULL                               | 2975 | Using index condition; Using where |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | backend_ubq     | eq_ref | PRIMARY,backend_ubq_department_2cef48a6c5825cef_uniq,backend_ubq_sub_department_65793aef847267e8_uniq,backend_ubq_department_2ebadbdc749719ff_idx                                        | PRIMARY                                           | 4       | xxxxxxxxxxx.backend_ubqstat.ubq_id |    1 | Using where                        |
+----+-------------+-----------------+--------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------+---------+------------------------------------+------+------------------------------------+
```

One week only (second query):

```
+----+-------------+-----------------+--------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------+---------+------------------------------------+------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table           | type   | possible_keys                                                                                                                                                                            | key                                               | key_len | ref                                | rows | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-----------------+--------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------+---------+------------------------------------+------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | backend_ubqstat | ref    | backend_ubq_store_number_4ba08aefde7a0fdc_uniq,backend_ubq_ubq_id_2883f2962b976ce1_uniq,backend_ubq_week_of_year_534972be244e06dd_uniq,backend_ubqstat_week_of_year_1f3b84a6cf9999f7_idx | backend_ubqstat_week_of_year_1f3b84a6cf9999f7_idx | 4       | const,const                        | 1475 | Using where |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | backend_ubq     | eq_ref | PRIMARY,backend_ubq_department_2cef48a6c5825cef_uniq,backend_ubq_sub_department_65793aef847267e8_uniq,backend_ubq_department_2ebadbdc749719ff_idx                                        | PRIMARY                                           | 4       | xxxxxxxxx.backend_ubqstat.ubq_id |    1 | Using where |
+----+-------------+-----------------+--------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------+---------+------------------------------------+------+-------------+
```

These are the schema of the two tables:
Table of products:
mysql> describe backend_ubq;

```
+----------------+----------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field          | Type                 | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------------+----------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id             | int(11)              | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| ub             | varchar(30)          | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| department     | varchar(30)          | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| sub_department | varchar(50)          | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| family         | varchar(50)          | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| sub_family_id  | smallint(5) unsigned | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| sub_family     | varchar(50)          | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| brand          | varchar(50)          | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| quartile       | smallint(5) unsigned | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
+----------------+----------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

This table has 3604 rows.

Table of revenues per products split by week number and store number:
mysql> describe backend_ubqstat;

```
+-----------------------+----------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field                 | Type                 | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------------------+----------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id                    | int(11)              | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| ubq_id                | int(11)              | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| week_of_year          | smallint(5) unsigned | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| month_of_year         | smallint(5) unsigned | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| year                  | smallint(5) unsigned | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| store_number          | smallint(5) unsigned | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| nb_tickets            | smallint(5) unsigned | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| nb_items              | smallint(5) unsigned | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| revenue               | decimal(9,2)         | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| complementary_revenue | decimal(9,2)         | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-----------------------+----------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

This table has 20 832 730 of rows.

I am using MySQL 5.6.

I have done some research but I am unable to find a solution for my issue. What should I need to do to make the first query run much faster?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the column is even indexed and you use `OR` the optimizer will fail to use the index. For your case if the column `week_of_year` is not indexed then you may index this column. Now to get rid of the issue you can use `UNION` and move the `OR` conditions as 2 different queries something as below. Try using `Explain` and see what you get.

```
SELECT 
SUM(`backend_ubqstat`.`complementary_revenue`) AS `complementary_revenue__sum`, 
SUM(`backend_ubqstat`.`revenue`) AS `revenue__sum` 
FROM `backend_ubqstat` 
INNER JOIN `backend_ubq` ON ( `backend_ubqstat`.`ubq_id` = `backend_ubq`.`id` ) 
WHERE 
(
  `backend_ubqstat`.`store_number` = 389 AND `backend_ubqstat`.`week_of_year` = 2 
  AND (`backend_ubq`.`department` = 'QUINCAILLERIE' OR `backend_ubq`.`department` = 'OUTILLAGE') 
  AND (`backend_ubq`.`sub_department` = 'Outillage à moteur' OR `backend_ubq`.`sub_department` = 'Outillage à main' OR `backend_ubq`.`sub_department` = 'Outil d\'assemblage')
)
union
SELECT 
SUM(`backend_ubqstat`.`complementary_revenue`) AS `complementary_revenue__sum`, 
SUM(`backend_ubqstat`.`revenue`) AS `revenue__sum` 
FROM `backend_ubqstat` 
INNER JOIN `backend_ubq` ON ( `backend_ubqstat`.`ubq_id` = `backend_ubq`.`id` ) 
WHERE 
(
  `backend_ubqstat`.`store_number` = 389 AND `backend_ubqstat`.`week_of_year` = 3 
  AND (`backend_ubq`.`department` = 'QUINCAILLERIE' OR `backend_ubq`.`department` = 'OUTILLAGE') 
  AND (`backend_ubq`.`sub_department` = 'Outillage à moteur' OR `backend_ubq`.`sub_department` = 'Outillage à main' OR `backend_ubq`.`sub_department` = 'Outil d\'assemblage')
)
```

Comment: Your solution works well. I confirm that week_of_year is already indexed.

Comment: Ok, in the query you are getting the `sum` so the result might be in 2 rows which needs to be summed up again for the final sum.